# How do I get `@Column(name="productName")` to not be ignored by Spring Boot + JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Sorry for the long details, but I wanted to be clear and thorough ...

I'm using Sprint Boot 2.3.4 with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-web` in the pom.xml with MySQL 8 on Mac.

```
DB Table Name: `productDef`
DB Columns: `id` | `productName`
```

My entity looked like this ...

```
@Entity
public class ProductDef {
    private Integer id;
    private String productName;
    /* ... */
}
```

Hibernate complained that it couldn't find table "product_def".

(My understanding is) this is because the default physical naming strategy determines the table name by converting class name "ProductDef" to "product_def".

So I added a `@Table` annotation like this, but that did not fix the problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="productDef")
public class ProductDef {
    private Integer id;
    private String productName;
    /* ... */
}
```

To make the annotation work, I also had to implement a custom physical naming strategy like so ...

```
package com.myapp.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.Identifier;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl;
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment;

public class RealNamingStrategyImpl extends org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy implements Serializable {

    public static final PhysicalNamingStrategy INSTANCE = new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(name.getText(), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(name.getText(), name.isQuoted());
    }

}
```

And add it to the `application.properties` file like so:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.myapp.dao.RealNamingStrategyImpl
```

Then the `@Table(name="productDef")` annotation works.

However --

Hibernate now complains that it cannot find column "product_name" (for the object property "productName").

I added annotation `@Column(name="productName")` but it did not work.  The `@Column` annotation appears to be ignored.

I found a similar question about this on Stackoverflow here ... [Spring Boot + JPA : Column name annotation ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283198/spring-boot-jpa-column-name-annotation-ignored)

I tried the solution from there, adding these to the `application.properties` ...

First tried this ...

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

... then tried this ...

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

But neither worked.

`@Column(name="productName")` continues to be ignored.

QUESTION: How do I get `@Column(name="productName")` to not be ignored?

(Also note, I found [a discussion thread here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2129) that leads me to believe this could be a bug in Spring Boot?)

Comment: how are you getting the table created? using sql or setting ddl-auto to true? Could you share the ddl if you are using any?

Comment: I'm creating the table with a SQL script ... looks like this ...  
CREATE TABLE `productDef` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

Comment: @AvaTaylor, did you find a solution for that ?